# Telerik winforms Grid View Header Title

Tags: winforms, telerik

i need to put a title header in Telerik Gridview in winforms.
i tried

```
radGridView1.MasterGridViewTemplate.Columns["myColumn"].HeaderText = "first line \n Second line \n third line";
```

but it doesn't work. my referred link : 
    http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/gridview/2-lines-of-text-in-the-column-header.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I tested the following and it is working:

In the designer set AutoSizeMode = **ColumnHeader**

[image]

Then add this line of code:

```
  this.radGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "This is a \n multiline \n header text";
```

Please note that the index [0] is relevant my test code. You shall set your column index considering that the first column is 0.

This is the result I got:

[image]

Let us know if this works for you.

Comment: hi, it doesn't work. in normal Gridview may its fine. i couldn't find the option which u mentioned in telerik grid.

Comment: Are you using a radgridview in in winforms? Which error you have? The first picture shows clearly the property to change in the designer. How is it possible you do not find it? Which version of Telerik you have?

Comment: Then it shall work even if you do not set the property AutoSizeMode. Have you set the column index to the index of your column? Where have you placed the code line in the context of your code?

Comment: So, what is the outcome? Have you checked the index of the column and which is the position of the line in your code?

Comment: I think you have a previous version than mine. However, as I said it should work even without setting the property as I tested it. Try to place that line of code directly under InitializeComponent();{here} and set the index using the number you see in your designer on the left.

Comment: hi, is that grid title option available in Telerik Q1 2013?

Comment: The version I am using is 2013 Q3. So yes that property is available in 2013.3. However, as I already said, the multiline works even without setting that property. Just use the line of code I gave you in my answer and will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the text as you mentioned, the text will be multiline, but the header cell height is not enough, hence you are not able to see that other lines. You can change the header cells height by using this property:

```
radGridView1.TableElement.TableHeaderHeight = 100;
radGridView1.MasterGridViewTemplate.Columns[0].HeaderText = "first line \n Second line \n third line";
```

Alternative way to do that is to use the AutoSizeRows property (set to **true**), but this will auto size all rows in the grid according to their content, not just the header row.